# CURL: Failed to connect Port 80: connection refused

Tags: curl

I wrote this CURL statement:

```
curl -H "AuthenticationToken:XXX" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -X PUT -d '{"targetQuantity" : 2}' \
    http://10.105.XX.XX:8080/webapp/api/v1/productionOrder/id/6690
```

It should change the "targetQuantity" to the value '2'.

But I get the following error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
>
> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2

How can I find my (syntax) mistake?